# Does iOS Simulator Save Core Data?

Tags: xcode, core-data, ios-simulator

Everytime I run my app on the iOS Simulator, the current data I have stored is reset. I was wondering if this is natural for the simulator to do that, or if it is something with my code? If I run it on my phone, it works when I double tap home & close the app, but if it crashes, it resets. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Saving works the same in the simulator as on a device. It's not normal for simulator data to just disappear under any circumstances.

**However**, note that each type of simulated phone is, in effect, a different simulator. If you simulate once on a simulated iPhone 6 and then on a simulated iPhone 6+, it's normal for data saved in one to not be available in the other.

Comment: Thanks! Figured out my error, I forgot to save it to core data when I created a new entry. Also, when declaring the array I had `var objects: [NSManagedObject] = []` instead of `var objects = [NSManagedObject]()`, if that matters. Thanks again!